# Why would Installshield 2010 not deploy updated components on a upgrade?

Tags: installation, installshield, installshield-2010

I have an install shield project that has gone through various versions, currently it is version 3.7.
There is a component in the project that contains four vdb files, which are set to always overwrite.
When installing the software on a fresh machine it works fine. The four files are copied in to the target dir. 
If I perform an upgrade on a previous version say 3.6 the files are ignored and the contents of the dir are unchanged (previously contained 2 files).

I have also set the Reinstallmode to amus.

Are there any other methods of ensuring that the files are overwritten / component deployed?

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful to see the install log, and the relevant row from the component table.

Comment: is overwrite option enabled at the components folder level or at the file level? check that.